# How to query the sdp records on local PC?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, perl

I'm using Net::Bluetooth to create an RFCOMM socket on my Linux box. I need for it to register with SDP with a specific UUID. [The perl code can be viewed in this link](https://superuser.com/questions/142288/how-to-configure-linux-to-act-as-a-bluetooth-rfcomm-spp-server).

I am unable to make the connection from a remote device however. This remote device (my Android phone) is able to connect to other RFCOMM devices using this UUID.

I would like to troubleshoot the problem, but I can't find a way to browse the LOCAL SDP records of my PC where the Perl script is running (and waiting for incoming BT connections).

Does anybody know how to browse the SDP records on the local PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sdptool browse local
```

(sdptool is somewhere in the bluez-utils or similar package).